# Why I cannot install the project templates that I created in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net-core, vsix, project-template

I have created C# projet template with a Vsix project inside it (for wizards). But when I try to pack it with other templates and install it, It didn't work.

My project folder looks like following:
[project template folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy6Ei.png)

I have included a `template.json` file as well. It is inside the .template.config folder.
Also in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hpNFrY_faI) youtube video, it recommends to add `.ide.host.json` file to show the template in visual studio. Although I added that and install the template again it didn't work.

Comment: how does your %appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<visual studio version>\ItemTemplatesCache\<language for which you have developed template> look like?

Comment: @vish it has a folder called "General" and inside that it has "RuleSet.zip" folder.

Comment: In my case the template I had developed was under `%appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ItemTemplatesCache\Visual C#\<my template name .zip>` folder. Inside that there need to be at least three files: .ico, .template and .cs\.cpp\.vb. You can try manually creating that and see if it works.